# BigQuery row objects use too much memory/alternatives?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

The current methodology with the BigQuery PHP API is to convert the result set into objects. Is there a way to just return the raw rows (skipping the conversion to objects / native to the library) or will I have to edit the library to force it to do so?

Comment: AFAIK you need to hack the library.

Comment: ah, @Pentium10 not ideal, the use of objects for each row when dealing with larger result sets seems to be using up quite a lot of memory.

Comment: please define what's quite a lot?

Comment: @Pentium10 On 36,000 rows, it takes 3-5 seconds to convert to the object structure and takes over 200mb of memory (which isnt really a big issue in of itself as we can up the limit) however we could see larger result sets, which would just mean proportionally more time/memory used.